# Core location wont work

Tags: ios, location, coordinates, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have been trying to make an app that allows the user to retrieve the current location using the core location framework. I wanted to be able to get the coordinates of the device that is using the app when the app launches and be able to display them using UILabels. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong or what adjustments I should make to the code?

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitude;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *altitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *speed;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

CLLocationManager *locationManager;

[super viewDidLoad];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
locationManager.delegate = self; // I set the delegate of locationManager to self.
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error retrieving your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[errorAlert show];
NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
_latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
_longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
_altitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f m",crnLoc.altitude];
_speed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f m/s", crnLoc.speed];
}



@end
```

I get these 2 errors.

```
Assigning to 'id<CLLocationManagerDelegate> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'


'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not implementing the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, which is why you get the first error. You could implement it like this:

```
@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end
```

You should also check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) for the methods that you'll need to implement in order to conform to that protocol, which you'll have to write in your `@implementation`. Only after conforming to that protocol is this assignment allowed:

```
locationManager.delegate = self; // I set the delegate of locationManager to self.
```

The second issue appears to be a warning. Apple did deprecate `UIAlertView` in iOS 9.0 and it has been replaced by `UIAlertController`, so you should use that instead. [This](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) NSHipster article explains how to use and compares it with the old, deprecated, version, which is interesting, but it's in Swift (I'm leaving it for the discussion they present). [Here](http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/) you'll also find some examples in Objective-C. Here's an example as shown on that last link:

```
UIAlertController * view= [UIAlertController
                               alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                                                message:@"Select you Choice"
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    //Do some thing here
                                    [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES     
                                                             completion:nil];
}];

UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                        [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];


[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```